# Does video/audio persist in single page MEAN apps when clicking to another page?

Tags: javascript, mean-stack

**I'm building a single page app using the MEAN stack.** Let's say there are three "links" in the dashboard - Home / Music / Settings.

On my music page I have a list of Youtube videos that are embedded and can be played directly from the music page.

If I were to start the Youtube video and click to the settings page, will the youtube video continue to play?

Comment: That depends on how you get to the settings page, redirecting will always stop currently playing audio/video regardless of what the serverside looks like.

Comment: Single page apps don't usually redirect or reload the page do they? I was under the impression that everything loads at once into memory... I may be wrong though.

Comment: Yes, if you have a single page app, it doesn't reload, it just loads new views, but that depends on how you set things up, using Node, Express and even Angular doesn't mean you can't redirect the regular way, did you build a one page app? Why don't you just try it and see if it keeps playing.

Comment: I'm in the process of building it. I wanted to get some insight first so I know what direction I should take. Thanks for taking the time to respond to my question.